# How to put xml template inside vue component property

Tags: vue.js, nativescript

I'm using a custom view plugin in NativeScript, and in its documentation: https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-filter-select

There's an option to add an item template with xml.

In my mind, I should pass it like this:

```
<FilterSelect
    item_template=" xml template here "
/>
```

I've tried this:

```
<FilterSelect
    item_template="<Label col='0' text='{{ ${this._search_param} }}' 
    textWrap='true' />"
```

But doesn't work. (Doesn't render)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What you mean by it doesn't work, the plugin won't work at all after this Or it doesn't render the template as expected Or do you see any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make this syntax work you would need to use es6 template literals. So with your example, this would look like this:

```js
<FilterSelect 
   :item_template="`
     <Label col='0' text='{{ ${this._search_param} }}' textWrap='true' />
   `"
/>
```

This should allow you to use `${}` string interpolation. Also don't forget to close your tag.

Comment: That worked! But i needed to add a colon ' : ' at item_template to go! Thanks a lot!

Comment: ohh yeah you're right, since you bind to a custom property. I've updated it.